# Difference of IDE0067 vs CA2000

Tags: c#, idisposable, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm using the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers`package analyzers (2.9.7) to detect undisposed `IDisposable`-s in a C# project. Such issues seems to be detected by 2 different analyzers, effectively reporting the same issue twice:

> Warning    CA2000  Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object created by 'xxx' before all references to it are out of scope.

vs

> Message    IDE0067 Disposable object created by 'xxx' is never disposed

Theres [some documentation about CA2000](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2000?view=vs-2019), but I found no such page for IDE0067 for comparison. I've also noted CA2000 seems to be able to detect more issues than IDE0067 on the same codebase, hinting that they are doing different things.

**What exactly is the difference between these 2 analyzers? Why have 2 (with different default severity)?**

Comment: The descriptions seem to indicate that check for almost  opposite things.  The first is if you dispose of something before it goes out of scope while the second warns if the object is not disposed at all.

Comment: @juharr , no. The CA2000 warning intent is "call (TO) dispose", not "call (OF) dispose". For example, trigger by `var a = new MemoryStream();` to see both warnings.